# Unexpected token in PropTypes (expected ",")

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

In the following code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  Avatar, Menu, MenuItem, Tooltip, Box,
} from '@mui/material';

import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
import { positions } from '@mui/system';

const menuItems = ['Test', 'Yes', 'No'];

function PositionedMenu(props) {
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);
  const open = Boolean(anchorEl);
  const { boxStyle: PropTypes.object} = props;
...
```

I am getting the following error in the specific position - PropTypes.object (where I validate boxStyles):
Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ",".

Why is this happening? I'm using React with eslint set to airbnb options.

Answer (score 0):

You are destructuring on that line, if you want to set default value, you need to use `=` char and not `:`

`const { boxStyle = PropTypes.object} = props;`

And yes, this is not the way to set propTypes. Here's example from docs:

Class based:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class Greeting extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <h1>Hello, {this.props.name}</h1>
    );
  }
}

Greeting.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string
};
```

Function based:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

function HelloWorldComponent({ name }) {
  return (
    <div>Hello, {name}</div>
  )
}

HelloWorldComponent.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string
}

export default HelloWorldComponent
```

Sometimes when setting up props we think that `prop` is only of type `object`. But due to a lot of factors (for example, how we fetch data and set props) a prop can be `undefined` for an initial period of time (very short) and then be defined as an `object` once the data is loaded.

To avoid you can either:

1. Change the way the data is supplied and therefore make sure that the prop is always an `object`
2. Allow in propTypes for both values: `undefined` (for initial moment) and then `object` as well once it loads. Here's how to specify multiple propTypes (without the use of default props):

```
// An object that could be one of many types
  optionalUnion: PropTypes.oneOfType([
    PropTypes.string,
    PropTypes.number,
    PropTypes.instanceOf(Message)
  ]),
```

Comment: I see what you mean, however props should be of type object (more precisely - a style) and when I try to do PropTypes.object I'm getting 2 errors:
1. Prop-type "object" is forbidden
2. propType "boxStyle" is not required, but has no corresponding defaultProps decleration

Comment: I don't have access to rest of your code, sounds like `boxStyle` might not be supplied as a prop and therefore you can't restructure it from `props`, not really sure why you want to set `boxStyle` to `PropTypes.object` value anyway.. have a look at examples on how to set prop types in React as I've added to my answer

Comment: Can you share the code you're looking at when you get those above errors now?

Comment: What do you mean ```boxStyle``` is not supplied as a prop? When I use this component I am indeed passing boxStyle...

Comment: I've actually solved this with `PositionedMenu.propTypes = { boxStyle: PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.object()),};` and `PositionedMenu.defaultProps = { boxStyle: undefined,};`

Comment: I think I know what is happening... I'll edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can pass **boxStyle** parent to child component and use it.

```
  // Parent component
  function ParentComponent(props) {
    render(
      <childComponent boxStyle={{ background: 'red'}} />
    )
  }

  // Child Component
  function childComponent(props) {
    const { boxStyle } = props;
    const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);
    const open = Boolean(anchorEl);
  }
  
  childComponent.propTypes = {
    boxStyle: PropTypes.object
  };
```

Comment: I need to take the value for boxStyle from props though

Comment: You can get directly from parent component and you can pass in child component like <child boxStyle ="your value" />
You can receive value in child component  
const { boxStyle } = props;